# C#. Загрузить один поток/ядро процессора на полную

Tags: c#, .net, производительность, процессор

Необходимо написать код, который загрузит **один поток** процессора на 100%. Код должен выполняться за конечное время в зависимости от мощности железа. Например если слабый процессор за 10 секунд, если более мощный за 5. Пытался дробить и перемножать числа в цикле, но процессору пофиг, он выполняет эту задачу используя только небольшой процент ресурсов ядра. Какой задачей можно нагрузить одно ядро/поток процессора на 100%?

Comment: @ГеннадийП нет, я хочу загрузить на 100% одно ядро/поток

Comment: Как вы определили, что он загружает только небольшой процент ресурсов ядра? И приведите код цикла который нагружает процессор. В настройках сборки оптимизация кода включена или выключена?

Comment: @ГеннадийП посмотрел загруженность в диспетчере задач

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Достаточно бесконечного цикла чтобы загрузить одно ядро полностью, даже вычисления внутри не обязательны. Но ОС все будет перекидывать поток между ядрами. Чтобы этому помешать, можно использовать функцию WinAPI SetThreadAffinityMask:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern UIntPtr SetThreadAffinityMask(IntPtr hThread, UIntPtr dwThreadAffinityMask);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetCurrentThread();

void Foo() 
{
    SetThreadAffinityMask(GetCurrentThread(), (UIntPtr)1);
    while(true) { }
}
```